# Submit Lotus Notes XPage form from outside with plain JS

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, xpages

I have a simple Lotus Notes XPage with only an editable RichText dialog that is embedded in a bigger form using an iframe.

The bigger form has a submit button, which triggers some javascript and finally a notes agent which saves all non-richtext values that are inside the bigger form.

Of course the user shall not have to use two submit buttons, so I won't have a (visible) submit button for the XPage. Instead, I want to use javascript to tell the iframe to submit the form.

Using `iframe.document.forms[0].submit()` does not work - the form is indeed submitted to the Notes server, but XPages won't save the changes I made.

Using a simple XPage button with the action "Save Data Sources", saving works like a charm, but I don't want the user to have to click two buttons in the correct order.

I also tried the following javascript code to fill some invisible fields with the values that IBM submits to the server, but this does not help either:

```
iframe.document.forms[0].elements["view:_id1:inputRichText1_h"].value = iframe.document.forms[0].elements["view:_id1:inputRichText1"].value;
iframe.document.forms[0].elements["view:_id1:inputRichText1_mod"].value = true;
iframe.document.forms[0].elements["$$xspsubmitid"].value="view:_id1:_id4";
iframe.document.forms[0].elements["$$xspsubmitscroll"].value="0|0";
iframe.document.forms[0].submit();
```

So now I ask you: how to correctly submit that form content, without the user actually clicking the XPages button? Can I programmatically trigger a click on that button, which would be indifferent from a human actually clicking, except for the human?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have an ordinary div with a fixed id and inside this div have a computedtext that will compute the clientsideid of the "save button" and return that inside the div

and use this clientside js code to do the actual click

var id=iframe.document.getElementById("button").innerHTML

var button=iframe.document.getElementById(id)

button.click()